# remove whitespace in between non alphanumeric character

Tags: java, regex

How do I remove whitespaces in between  non-alphanumeric characters? For example

> ```
> anti - C6 / 36 membrane antibodies 
> D2 NS1 - P1 - specific antibodies
> ```

To

> ```
> anti-C6/36 membrane antibodies 
> D2 NS1-P1-specific antibodies
> ```

Comment: Should we also include dot `.` as alphabetic? Is it possible to have input like `Mr. Adams`?

Answer (score 1):

```
(?<=\W)[ ]+|[ ]+(?=\W)
```

Try this.Replace by `empty string`.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/zB3hI5/11

For java it will be

```
(?<=\\W)[ ]+|[ ]+(?=\\W)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this lookaround based regex for search:

```
(?<![\p{L}\p{N}]) +| +(?![\p{L}\p{N}])
```

And replace it by empty string.

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/yG1tU6/3)

**In Java:**

```
String repl = input.replaceAll( "(?<![\\p{L}\\p{N}]) +| +(?![\\p{L}\\p{N}])", "" );
```

`(?<![\p{L}\p{N}]) | (?![\p{L}\p{N}])` means match a space if it is not followed by an alphanumeric or if not preceded by an an alphanumeric.

Answer (score 0):

Try regex like this :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String s1 = "anti - C6 / 36 membrane antibodies";
    String s2 = "D2 NS1 - P1 - specific antibodies";
    String pattern = "\\s+(?=[^a-zA-Z0-9]+)|(?<=[^a-zA-Z0-9])\\s+";// replace all spaces either preceeded by or followed by a non-alphanumeric character
    System.out.println(s1.replaceAll(pattern, ""));
    System.out.println(s2.replaceAll(pattern, ""));
}
```

O/P:

```
anti-C6/36 membrane antibodies
D2 NS1-P1-specific antibodies
```